# Remove spacing between items in linear layout in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout, android-linearlayout

[image: screenshot of layout]

I was wondering how can I remove spacing between two buttons in a linear layout, please notice that I tried padding, margin, and weights.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried most of the attributes but not got any result. But If you can fill your button with any default or custom color then It'll fill with the parent. Just try this `android:background="@color/black"` attribute in your `AppCompactButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative values for margins to adjust the views and close gaps between them.

In your case you can achieve this by setting marginRight for the left button and marginLeft for the right button with -3dp or -3.5dp as their value, depending on how close you want the views to be.

Be careful when setting negative values since views might end up overlapping each other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, notice that I replaced `fill_parent` with `match_parent` which is the modern way to refer to this setting, although `fill_parent` will still work.